# Listen to tab switches on the panels of a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I've developed a simple Swing GUI to allow the user to edit the data of my application. The UI is rather simple:

- A JFrame that contains a JTabbedPane.
- Each of the tabs consists of one subclass of JPanel that offers tools to edit an aspect of the data.
- The data itself is contained in one object and a reference is passed to each of the JPanels.

But there's a problem: I need to sync the different JPanels.

For example, the data object stores a list of persons and a list of tasks.

- One JPanel allows the user to edit the persons. He can create new Persons and delete existing ones.
- The second JPanel allows the user to assign persons to tasks.

Both JPanels are initialized when they are first opened. The components are created and the layout is set. Now the user can start to work with the UI.

1. He opens the first tab of the JTabbedPane and creates a the first Person.
2. He opens the second tab. The Components of the second tab are initialized and list the one person that is available. He assigns a task.
3. He returns to the first tab and creates a second person.
4. He switches back to the second tab to deal with the new person.

But the second tab and the JPanel it contains have already been initialized. The user will not see the second person, unless the JPanel is updated. I have implemented a custom update method on my JPanel subclass for tab 2. But how do I call it ?

I need the Swing event that is fired on a Component, when it is redrawn.

Comment: You should have a GUI data model, that contains all of the person and task information.  Each JPanel would update, and be updated by the contents of the data model through controller actions.  This is the model / view / controller architecture for building GUI applications.

Comment: I know the MVC pattern. Swing pretty much forces you to use it. What I am trying to implement is the controller. I just need to find a way to let the controller know when the data was updated. Victor Seifert gave the perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually updating the second panel when the first gets redrawn is bad idea even if you manage to find the event that gets fired.  This would cause the second panel to be updated on every redraw of the first panel, regardless of wether the redraw means that the undelying data has changed or not (think about unsaved data).

You should make the data your tabs maipulate `Observable` (or `Subject` from [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)).  Then each tab can react to changes in the data instead of changes in other tabs.  This will reduce the time of updates to only when it is really needed and also will decouple the tabs from one another.

The data may repesent changes by firing [PropertyChangeEvent's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html).  These in turn should trigger Controller actions as suggested by Gilber Le Blanc in the comments.

Comment: great, exactly what i was looking for